# (jQuery to Vanilla Javascript) fixed floating element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not a big fan of jQuery because it can cause a bigger load time on the page load(even if it's small), so I refrain from using jQuery as much as possible.

I am trying to convert this jQuery code to plain javascript, could someone lead me in the correct direction?

Non-working non-jquery javascript

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var scrolledElement = document.querySelector('#comment');
    var top = scrolledElement.offsetTop;

    window.scroll(function()
    {
        var y = window.pageYOffset;

        if (y >= top)
        {
            scrolledElement.classList.add('fixed');
        } else {
            scrolledElement.classList.remove('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the actual code for jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('#comment').offset().top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {

    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= top) {

      $('#comment').addClass('fixed');
    } else {

      $('#comment').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is what I have so far in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/knjQh/29/

Comment: @muistooshort that is definitely a typo, but it has no effect on the code, thank you for pointing it out tho.

Comment: I'd use `addEventListener` (without regard for old IE's `attachEvent` since you're using `document.querySelector` anyway) instead of `window.[event]`. When you use `window.[event]` you can only attach one event handler at a time for that particular event.

Comment: Oh, and also, you're using `document.querySelector('#comment')`. You can use `document.getElementById('comment')` instead. Not that using `querySelector` is a bad thing, but `getElementById` is more explicit on its intent, and it's compatible with older browsers.

Comment: I had just changed that actually but thank you for the suggestion. The answer below has added a listen event instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Update your JS to attach a event on scroll

```
window.onload = function () {
    var scrolledElement = document.querySelector('#comment');
    var top = scrolledElement.offsetTop;
    var listener = function () {
        var y = window.pageYOffset;

        if (y >= top) {
            scrolledElement.classList.add('fixed');
        } else {
            scrolledElement.classList.remove('fixed');
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listener, false);
}
```

Check

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/knjQh/33/

Comment: I see, that makes sense. (Hmm). I appreciate your time, thank you.